# How to remove unwanted output?

Tags: verilog, hardware-acceleration, register-transfer-level

I am working on a very large module in which this multiplier and adder module is a small part, but it will help me to express my question here.

**RTL code:**

```
module mul_and_add #(parameter BITS = 32,
parameter SHIFT = 15
)

(
  clk,
  i_multiplicand,
  i_multiplier,
  i_adder,
  o_result
);

input clk;
input signed  [BITS-1:0]    i_multiplicand;
input signed  [BITS-1:0]    i_multiplier;
input signed  [BITS-1:0]    i_adder;
output signed [BITS-1:0]    o_result;

reg signed    [2*BITS-1:0]  mul_result;
reg signed    [BITS:0]      add_result;
wire signed   [BITS-1:0]    o_result;

always @(posedge clk)

begin

mul_result <= i_multiplicand * i_multiplier;
add_result <=  i_adder + (mul_result >> SHIFT);

end

assign o_result = add_result[BITS-1:0];

endmodule
```

**TB code:**

```
module tb_mul_and_add (
                        );

parameter BITS = 32;

reg  clk;
reg  signed [ BITS - 1 : 0 ] i_multiplicand;
reg  signed [ BITS - 1 : 0 ] i_multiplier;
reg  signed [ BITS - 1 : 0 ] i_adder;

wire signed [ BITS - 1 : 0 ] o_result;

mul_and_add mul_and_add_i (
    .clk(clk),
    .i_multiplicand(i_multiplicand),
    .i_multiplier(i_multiplier),
    .i_adder(i_adder),
    .o_result(o_result)
                  );

parameter CLKPERIODE = 10;

initial clk = 1'b1;
always #(CLKPERIODE/2) clk = !clk;

initial begin
  i_multiplicand =  32'h00010000;
  i_multiplier =    32'h00010000;
  i_adder =     32'h00010000;
  #30
  i_multiplicand = 32'h00008000;
  i_multiplier = 32'h00010000;
  i_adder = 32'h00020000;
  #70
  $finish();
end

endmodule
```

**Output: Cadence SimVision**

[image: Output from Cadence SimVision]

The data marked with red rectangle is the unwanted data which I want to get rid of because when I use this module several times there are many unwanted data before the correct one. So when I have to sort out the data to plot a graph, it's a lot to go through.

What magic trick is there which I am not aware of to get rid of the unwanted data?

Also, if you have an idea for better optimization or any criticism, please feel free to share.

Comment: @toolic `i_multiplier` input is always the same and I will have different `i_multiplicand` each time. After that, there will be always a new variable which will be added after the multiplication and then only I want my output. I hope this answers your query.

Comment: *"So when I have to sort out the data to plot a graph it's a lot to go through."* If you move on in this field you should start writing self-checking test benches. The standard procedure in cases like this is to generate a 'valid' signal which indicates when the output is correct.

Comment: do not use <= here: `mul_result = i_multiplicand * i_multiplier;` You will get the correct result every cycle then. `mul_result` is not an output of the flop, but is an intermediate variable only.

Comment: @Oldfart I think that is a really good suggestion. Could you please give me an example or a reference or a link of a tutorial? Anything that will help me to understand a bit more.

Comment: Here is some text I wrote about self-checking test benches: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/352968/self-checking-test-bench-verilog/352991#352991 As stated in there predicting the outcome can be as difficult as writing the code yourself. An alternative is to use files with input and output patterns which can be externally generated using e.g. C/C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the RTL code to make `mul_result` a wire, instead of having a one cycle delay for the calculation:

```
wire signed   [2*BITS-1:0]  mul_result = i_multiplicand * i_multiplier;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    add_result <= i_adder + (mul_result >> SHIFT);
end
```

Change the TB code to align input changes to the clock edge and use non-blocking assignments to avoid race conditions:

```
initial begin
  i_multiplicand =  32'h00010000;
  i_multiplier =    32'h00010000;
  i_adder =     32'h00010000;
  repeat (3) @(posedge clk);
  i_multiplicand <= 32'h00008000;
  i_multiplier <= 32'h00010000;
  i_adder <= 32'h00020000;
  #70
  $finish();
end
```

As a coding style note, you can reduce clutter by using ANSI module ports:

```
module mul_and_add #(
    parameter BITS  = 32,
    parameter SHIFT = 15
)
(
   input clk,
   input signed  [BITS-1:0] i_multiplicand,
   input signed  [BITS-1:0] i_multiplier,
   input signed  [BITS-1:0] i_adder,
   output signed [BITS-1:0] o_result
);

reg signed    [BITS:0]      add_result;
wire signed   [2*BITS-1:0]  mul_result = i_multiplicand * i_multiplier;
always @(posedge clk) begin
    add_result <= i_adder + (mul_result >> SHIFT);
end

assign o_result = add_result[BITS-1:0];

endmodule
```